# WebGL/Three.js set mesh offset

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a question about `three.js`.
How do I set an offset to a mesh?
The basic code is available at: http://lukas.achatz.ws/tst/webgl_003.html

What I want is to set a position offset and also that point should be used as the rotation reference.

I tried: `mesh.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( -2, 0, 0 ) );` but this only moves the mesh in the scene.

Comment: Thanks Aurora and veljasije for proofreading.
@Aurora Why shouldn't there be a thanks?(removed closer/thanks)?

Comment: although not a strict rule, the usual StackExchange etiquette is to not include greetings and 'thanks' taglines. The idea is that the question should get to the point, and greetings/taglines are more appropriate for emails and private communication. Check out this thread for a discussion on the subject: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
var group = new THREE.Group();
scene.add( group );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( ..., ... );
mesh.position.set( -2, 0, 0 );
group.add( mesh );
```

Comment: Thanks mrdoob basicaly it works :)
I only wonder if there is a more performant way, couse if I get it right now there are allways 2 objects that will be rendered?

Comment: Nope. Still just one object that will be rendered. If anything, is one matrix transform that will be computed. But unless you have 5000 objects doing this, it should be pretty performant.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be performant? What could be more performant than this regarding object position transforming? matrix transoformation?